# "decide something" or "decide on something" in context?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please the correct sentence.

> We have yet to **decide** the share of the profit we will give them.
>
> We have yet to **decide on**  the share of the profit we will give them.

I think both are correct, and I am pretty sure there is a difference in meaning between sentences, but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very subtle difference between **decide sth** and **decide on sth**.

**Decide on** is used to **choose something from a number of almost similar possibilities(ppssibilities that would yield almost similar results, but it depends on your personal choice )** 
e.g

> We are still trying to **decide on** a venue.

This sentence implies that we have different venues that we can choose from.

> I have **decided on** yellow for this table.

It implies we have different colours available like red, green etc.
When you say

> We have yet to **decide on** the share of the profit we will give them.

This means you have different shares that you can give for example you can give them 5% share,2% share and 9% share.

If you say

> We have yet to **decide** the share of the profit we will give them.

It does not necessarily mean you have different equal possibilities (possiblities having similar results)